# foreign key does not update on cascade

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin 4.7.3 version. I made 2 tables with innoDB storage engine in a same database and i want to update foreign key automatically by using cascade but it does not work at all. In my **dineOwnerUser** table i have id field which is foreign key in **webpromo** table with the name of ownerid. Here are all step which i did to make it foreign key.

1. went to webpromo table
2. clicked on relation view button
3. after that i setup all option which is visible in image

[image: in webpromo table i did this to make a forign key]

So far i have explained which i have done the problem is that my webpromo table is totally empty even though foreign key is also not updating automatically. If i am wrong here kindly please guide me also I am posting my code just in case i am doing some thing wrong in coding here is my php code

```
    <?php
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['recaptcha'])){
        $secret = "************";
        $response = $_POST['recaptcha'];
        $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteip");
        $content = json_decode($url, TRUE);
        if($content['success'] ==1){
            function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            $data = strtolower($data);
            return $data;
            }
            $discount = test_input($_POST["discount"]);
            $discountitem = test_input($_POST["discountitem"]);
            $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
            $expirydate = test_input($_POST["expirydate"]);
            $desc = test_input($_POST["desc"]);
            $filename;
            if(isset($_FILES['logouploader']['name'])){
                $filename = basename($_FILES['logouploader']['name']);
                $filename = test_input($filename);
            }
            $dir = "img/uploads/";
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['logouploader']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $allowed =  array('jpeg','png' ,'jpg');
            if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
                echo "wrongext";
                $uploadOk = 0;
                exit;
            }
            if ($_FILES["logouploader"]["size"] > 600000) {
                echo "large";
                $uploadOk = 0;
                exit;
            }
            $uploadOk = 1;
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "Sorry";
                exit;
            }
            if ($uploadOk == 1) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logouploader"]["tmp_name"], $dir.$filename);
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "*****";
                $password = "*****";
                try {
                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=*********", $username, $password);
                    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $query = "INSERT INTO webpromo (discount, dealitem, website, expirydate, description, logouploader) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
                    $statement->execute(
                        array(
                        $discount,
                        $discountitem,
                        $website,
                        $expirydate,
                        $desc,
                        $filename
                        ) );
                        $conn = null;
                        exit;
                        echo "done";
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
        if($content['success'] !=1){
            echo "notok";
            $conn = null;
            exit;
        }
        $conn = null;
        exit;
    }
?>
```

> Note: i am getting image in my folder that's mean upto
>   **move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logouploader"]["tmp_name"], $dir.$filename);** my code is working fine

but after that when i try to populate my webpromo table with the form input values as well as uploaded image name it does not populate at all.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got the wrong idea my friend it does not mean your data will be automatically inserted if you are using **cascade**.

What is used for actually is if the **primary key value is updated then it updates the foreign key value in all respective tables.**
You have to write a seperate insert query.